# Search Arraylist for some letters

Tags: java, arraylist

Say I have an ArrayList with 5 items ( `Book, Black, Basketball, Bat, Kebab`). What if I want to search the list for "Ba s k" and return "Basketball". Also searching for "B K" returns "`Basketball`", "`Book`" and "`Black`" but not "`Kebab`".

How is this possible?

Comment: You can simply use regex to match any pattern you desire.

Comment: Ofcourse it's possible

Answer (score 0):

Just check for each character whether it exists in each elements of the List. This you can do in multiple ways one is having a nested loop one for input character and one for actual List.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do so using a regular expression:

```
// change the regex to as desired
final String REGEX = "^[B].*[k].*";

List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Book", "Black", "Basketball", "Bat", "Kebab");
List<String> collect = list.stream()
                         .filter(c -> c.matches(REGEX )) //apply regex here
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now as per your requirement you can specify the regex and pass it to the filter that uses `.matches(String regex)`. Now any *String* that matches the *regex* can be collected to another list.